# PowerShell Query needs to produce a timestamped file contained the Disabled AD accounts in each run

Tags: powershell

I have developed the following script to find the enabled AD users who are inactive for 90 days. The script will find those users disable and move them to the target OU. the script produces a text file in the ADAM folder when I run this script every day.

The problem I have is that whenever I run the script it keeps overriding the file produced in the previous run.

1. I want the script to produce a text file which contains the date so that I can figure out which dates the script is run.
2. I want the script to NOT to override the existing file, but to produce a new test file with datestamp whenever I run it.
3. I need the file to contain a list of disabled uses on that particular day. (That way if something happens, I can easily find the date on which the script run and see which accounts were disabled on that day)

Can you please help me to fix the problem? Thank you.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$inactiveDays = 90$
disableDaysInactive=(Get-Date).AddDays(-($inactiveDays)) 


$LogFile = "C:\Temp\ADAM\Disable_and_Move_User_Accounts.log"
$DisabledOU = 'OU=Disabled Accounts,OU=Car,DC=car,DC=com'
$Path= "OU=Test,OU=User Accounts,OU=Car,DC=car,DC=com" 

$userlist = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $path -Filter {(Enabled -eq $True)} -Properties * | Where-Object {($_.description -Notlike "*Service Account*") -and ($_.lastLogonDate -lt $disableDaysInactive) -and ($_.lastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} 

Start-Transcript -path $LogFile if ($userlist) 
{    
ForEach ($user in $userlist){        
$desc = "Disabled on $(Get-Date) for being inactive - $($user.Description)"         

try {            
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Description $desc -Enabled $false            
Move-ADObject -Identity $user -TargetPath $DisabledOU        
}        
catch {            
'Error occured updating account {0}. {1}' -f $user.SamAccountName, $_        
}

}}
else 
{    
"No users met the search criteria."
}
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: by looking at the documentation you can see that `Start-Transcript` has an `-Append` switch

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon, I can't see your full comment. Could you please repost ur comment? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new variable, like

```
$todaysDate = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
```

Which will return the date like `20230521`

And then replace

`$LogFile = "C:\Temp\ADAM\Disable_and_Move_User_Accounts.log"`

with `$LogFile = "C:\Temp\ADAM\Disable_and_Move_User_Accounts_$todaysDate.log"`

Which would create the file `Disable_and_Move_User_Accounts_20230521.log`

Comment: It worked thank you. Could you please let me know how to get the list of disabled users whenever the script is run to the logfile? @Anthony Norwood

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Your response was helpful. I used that and took it one step further. The issue was that the when I use only the date stamp and re run the script on the same day, the script overrides the existing file. To prevent that I have added time at the end of the format like this

$todaysDate = (Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HH-mm-ss")

Comment: I wanted to get the list of user who got disabled by the script into the text file. I got it done with the below section.

Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Description $desc -Enabled $false            
Move-ADObject -Identity $user -TargetPath $DisabledOU 
Write-Output $user.DisplayName

It is all sorted now. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate

Comment: Thanks @DarkKnight - if my answer has helped please do mark it as accepted. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, your answer is helpful. I marked as accepted. Thank you once again Anthony